# How to compare an integer with newline in C?

Tags: c, integer, compare, newline

I already know how to compare char type with newline (\n) but I would like to know how to compare an Integer with the newline (\n). Is it possible? 
(I did researches to find my answer but I end up getting answer that require char types)

I've the text file input with numbers:

```
11 22 33 44 55 1
2 3 4 56 777
1
255
3
5
```

I want the output to look like this

```
[11][22][33][44][55][1]<newline>[2][3][4][56][777]<newline>[1]<newline>[255]<newline>[3]<newline>[5]<newline>
lineNumber:[6]
```

but the output I get is

```
[11][22][33][44][55][1][2][3][4][56][777][1][255][3][5]
lineNumber:[0]
```

This is the code I'm using

```
int *integers = malloc(sizeof(int) * 200);
int i=0, lineNumber=0, num=0;
//int num;

while(fscanf(file, "%d", &num) > 0) 
{       
    if(num == '\n'){
        printf("<newline>");
        lineNumber++;
    }

    integers[i] = num;

    printf("[%d]", integers[i]); // Just to show output.
    i++;
}
printf("\nlineNumber:[%d]", lineNumber);
```

Reason why I don't want to use the char type is because I've to re-convert the char digits into integer... I would like to care about the newline (\n) and integers only

Comment: Your  if-case will never be met due to whitespace skipping. See the docs for [`fscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more info. Then see [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for ideas on alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attempt to read a newline character after each integer then check the return of fscanf to see how many items were read.

```
int *integers = malloc(sizeof(int) * 200);
int i=0, lineNumber=0, num=0;
int read;
char nl[2];

while((read=fscanf(file, "%d%[\n]", &num, &nl)) > 0) 
{       

    integers[i] = num;

    printf("[%d]", integers[i]); // Just to show output.
    i++;

    if(read == 2){
        printf("<newline>");
        lineNumber++;
    }
}
printf("\nlineNumber:[%d]", lineNumber);
```

Comment: It detects the newline but it has a side-effect, it changes the value of the number before the new line. It gives the number "0" if lower than 768 and "768" if lower than "1024". (It subtracts 256).

Comment: @LordRixuel try it with nl as char[2] instead of char

Comment: It works really, thank you very much. The number 2 means %[\n] right? and 1 is %d?

Comment: The `if(read == 2)` means that 2 items were read, the first one being the number and the second one being the newline.